# dynamic_cast and polymorphism

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

This is my first question on this site, so feel free to highlight any problems with my word choice, question structure, etc.

Recently, I started to use `dynamic_cast` when dealing with polymorphism, and I've read that `dynamic_cast` doesn't create another instance of the class but instead it creates another instance of the pointer to the object.

While testing `dynamic_cast`, I encountered this problem. Here is the code:

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>

class Base{
public:
    int BaseNum;
    virtual void BaseFunction(){};
};

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    int DerivedNum; 
    virtual void DerivedFunction(){};
};

int main(){

    Base * ptrBase = new Base;
    ptrBase->BaseNum = 0;
    Derived * ptrDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptrBase);
    ptrDerived->DerivedNum = 1;

    std::cout << ptrBase->BaseNum << ptrDerived->DerivedNum << std::endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The program crashed in the line:

```
ptrDerived->DerivedNum = 1;
```

While debugging, it said "unable to read memory". My conclusion was that I can't downcast if the original memory allocation was reserved for a class that was higher in the hierarchy, but I think I might be wrong.

Where did the code go wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` locates the requested class type within the specified object and returns a pointer/reference to that section of the object. If it cannot be found, a NULL is returned for a pointer cast, and a `std::bad_cast` exception is thrown for a reference cast. In your example, it fails because `ptrBase` is not pointing at an object that is an instance of the `Derived` class, so there is no `Derived` section within the object to return a pointer to, so it returns NULL.  You need to change this:

```
Base * ptrBase = new Base;
```

To this instead:

```
Base * ptrBase = new Derived;
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so basically dynamic_cast doesnt add anything in regards to memory allocation.

Comment: There is no allocation, just a pointer to a different memory address within the existing object.

Comment: @DiegoLiu: `dynamic_cast` says "Hey, find out if this is a `Derived`, and if it is, give me a pointer to that side of it.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are using dynamic cast backwards.

If you did

```
   Base *ptrBase = new Derived ;
```

Then it would work.

Derived IS A Base.
Base IS NOT A Derived.

Answer (score 1):

In your sample code, you create a new instance of `Base`:

```
Base * ptrBase = new Base;
ptrBase->BaseNum = 0;
Derived * ptrDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptrBase);
```

Since `Derived` is a superset of `Base`, but base is only a subset of `Derived`, you cannot address the object pointed to by `ptrBase` as being `Derived`, because it's 'smaller' than `Derived`.

If, on the other hand, you write

```
Base * ptrBase = new Derived;
ptrBase->BaseNum = 0;
Derived * ptrDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(ptrBase);
```

then everything is fine, because now the object pointed to by `ptrBase` is `Derived`.

With `dynamic_cast`, it's up to the programmer to ensure that the conversion is successful.

Comment: The compiler ensures the conversion is *legal*.  The programmer must ensure the conversion is *successful*, as the compiler cannot validate that at compile-time.